# What exactly being computed in this expression, and why?

Tags: c

```
#define NP_MAXREADY (((unsigned)(~0)<<1)>>1)
```

I take it as: fill register sized unsigned int with ones, then shake off MSB, obtaining maximum value for signed int. Is it correct? Also, the reason *why* they are doing it such way completely evades me, please enlighten.

Comment: Love the "magic" tag. :D

Comment: Appears to be from Mozilla npapi.h

Comment: @David: My [googling](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/npapi_8h.html) tells me it's from the [S60 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29), a popular mobile platform by Nokia (and apparently used by both Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: @BlueRaja One wonders who stole it from whom! I have a running instance of S60 in my pocket right now, as it happens!

Comment: Yes, npapi.h from Netscape/Mozilla codebase, Nokia adopted it too. I guess it is too old for handsets with plugin-capable browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may rewrite this as

```
#define NP_MAXREADY (((~0u)<<1)>>1)
```

then you'd notice that the inner shift operation is completely useless, since its only effect is to shift out the highest order bit

```
#define NP_MAXREADY ((~0u)>>1)
```

which in turn is nothing than

```
#define NP_MAXREADY (UINT_MAX/2)
```

Other than stated in another answer, this is not `INT_MAX`, since first of all this one here is an `unsigned`, so the type is different. Then the representation of `signed` versus `unsigned` may have padding bits, so you never can be sure that these two have the same value.

Comment: Technically more correct than my answer, though I think it's more likely the original author meant to use `INT_MAX` rather than `UINT_MAX/2`

Answer (score 7):

We'd have to see the code that uses it to be sure, but *"max value of a signed integer"* would also be my guess.

As for *why* they are doing it this way - probably because they don't know about [`INT_MAX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h#Member_constants)

Comment: It took a time for firefox trunk to arrive, and macro appear unused at all :-(